# Is MDF adequate for a cyclorama build?

Tags: mdf

I'm preparing to build a cyclorama (or cy wall), and I'm considering using MDF for the visible walls, as it's a lot of surface and MDF comes in cheap 3-4mm boards that will bend easy.

Project is 14 m2 (150 ft2) with 3 m (9 feet 10 7/64 inches) high walls, and the curve radius is 75 cm (30 inches).

The cyclorama has curved walls, it must be painted with special paint, and the seams and screw holes must be invisible (covered with plaster and sanded down), creating the illusion of an infinite wall with minimum shadow reflection.

Considering the MDF properties, can I expect to be able to hold both form (no warping) and unified appearance after primed and painted?

[image]

Comment: What are the overall dimensions of the cy wall and the radius of the curve?

Comment: This may be impossible to answer satisfactorily because MDF is, despite appearances, surprisingly variable. The quality varies loads depending on the source, which can be reflected in what you pay for it with generally the cheaper stuff being noticeably less good as you'd expect (but higher price is then not a guarantee of quality). So this comes down to what *this MDF* is like, which is unknown.

Comment: @Ashlar see edit, I added measurements : )

Comment: Often semi-permanent indoor skateboard "ramps" are made with similar material. You should research that.

Comment: While the curved wall intersections can be created since the board is only being bent into the curve, the curved corner intersections at the base require distorting the MDF material in three dimensions.  IMO, this is not really possible with MDF (it can be bent, but not deformed in the shop).  Those corners must be molded in that profile.

Comment: I concur with @Ashlar's observation above, the corner pieces may not be possible to make from MDF in the way you're hoping. Curvature in two directions (a *compound curve*) is not something that wood, or wood-based materials, take to easily at the best of times — it's challenging to get veneers, which are really really thin, the conform to even subtle compound curves.

Comment: That’s for sure, the corners require a special solution. But what about the rest? My concern are the seams and the plaster and paint cracking over time because of temp and humidity changes. If I nail *and* glue the boards and use sealant before priming, should it be enough?